# How to pass struct containing array to the kernel in CUDA?

Tags: c, arrays, cuda

In the following code I have an array in a struct which I need to pass to the kernel function. I can't seem to find the proper way. I tried looking at other posts on SO but do not understand their methods that well.

In my actual code, I receive two structs, as pointers, as arguments to the function from where the kernel is being called. Therefore, I need to copy the contents of these 'argument structs' to 'GPU memory structs' and pass them onto the kernel.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int *pass;
    int element;
}Pass;

__global__ void hello(int *a, int *b, Pass *p){

    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(i < *b)
        a[i] = p -> pass[i] + p -> element;
}

int main(){

    int *a_host, b_host = 5;
    int *a_gpu, *b_gpu;
    Pass *p, *p_gpu;

    a_host = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5); 
    cudaMalloc(&a_gpu, 5 * sizeof(int));

    cudaMalloc(&b_gpu, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(b_gpu, &b_host, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    p = (Pass*)malloc(sizeof(Pass));
    p -> pass = (int*)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
        p -> pass[i] = i;
    p -> element = 5;

    cudaMalloc(&p_gpu, sizeof(Pass));
    cudaMemcpy(p_gpu, p, sizeof(Pass), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int numBlocks = 1;
    int threadPerBlock = 512;


    hello<<<numBlocks, threadPerBlock>>>(a_gpu, b_gpu, p_gpu);

    cudaMemcpy(a_host, a_gpu, 5 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < 5;i++)
        printf("a[%d]: %d\n", i, a_host[i]);

    cudaFree(p_gpu);
    cudaFree(a_gpu);
    cudaFree(b_gpu);

    free(p);
    free(a_host);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I conclude that `c_host.sparseCount` is zero, or some other unexpected number.  I'm voting to close since you haven't provided an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (<-click on link, and read) which [SO expects for questions like these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @RobertCrovella So apart from this the logic is solid?

Comment: @MessyCoder: absolutely impossible to say. If you want help, post the shortest, simplest, *complete* example someone else could compile and run which exhibits the problem. Otherwise you are not going to get very far here

Comment: All of those `cudaMemcpy`  calls after the kerne launch are totally broken and are making the exact same mistakes you had in your previous question (albiet in reverse), as well as a pretty egregious buffer overflow.

Comment: @talonmies  I have updated the question now. Please take a look.

Comment: Did you read the duplicate question and answer linked to on your last question? You are still making the exact same mistake. You cannot access a pointer inside a structure in device memory from the  after you have allocated that structure. Make the device structure in *host*memory and then copy that structure to the device. It is clearly explained in the link I gave you

Comment: I am making the hostmemory structure in 'Pass *p' and then copying the struct to device memory p_gpu. I removed the array allocation and copy part. But I am still getting the garbage values. And yes I read the question you had linked earlier on. I am trying to make sense out of it by trying to write this down.

Comment: In other words, you are now passing a host pointer inside the structure to the device and expecting it to work, which it will obviously not. You have now posted what amounts to three different pieces of code with three different problems in this question so far. Trying to answer it is like trying to hit a moving target. I will repeat - the answer you need is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11875516/681865). That shows *exactly* what you have to do to correctly allocate a structure containing pointers using the CUDA host runtime API.

Comment: From what I understand,

Comment: From what I understand, 

cudaMalloc((void**)&h_nL.neurons, 6*sizeof(Neuron));

uses a dummy variable h_nl.neurons to get device address which later on gets copied to the nL in,

cudaMemcpy(nL, &h_nL, sizeof(NLayer), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

What I do not understand here is that if h_nL.neurons has some data, then how to copy that in to the neurons array in nL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have seen three different codes in this question in the first 24 hours of its existence. This answer addresses the final evolution.

The underlying problem you are having is with this type of operation:

```
cudaMalloc(&p_gpu, sizeof(Pass));
cudaMalloc(&p_gpu -> pass, 5 * sizeof(int));
```

The second `cudaMalloc` is illegal. This is attempting to dereference and assign a value to a pointer in device memory from the host. A segfault will result.

The correct process to allocate a structure on the device which includes pointers to other memory allocations is as follows:

1. Allocate memory for each of the arrays or objects which the structure pointers will point to on the device
2. Assign those allocations to a copy of the structure in *host memory*
3. Copy the full initialised structure in *host memory* to *device memory*

In the code in this question, this might look like this:

```
// p_hgpu is the device structure copy in host memory
// p_gpu is the device structure copy in device memory
Pass *p_gpu, *p_hgpu;
p_hgpu = (Pass*)malloc(sizeof(Pass));
p_hgpu->element = p->element;
cudaMalloc(&(p_hgpu->pass), sizeof(int) * 5);
cudaMemcpy(p_hgpu->pass, p->pass, sizeof(int) * 5, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// copy p_hgpu to the device
cudaMalloc(&p_gpu, sizeof(Pass));
cudaMemcpy(p_gpu, p_hgpu, sizeof(Pass), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

While this is straightforward, it contains several subtleties which are probably only self-evident if you possess a sound grasp of pointers and their use in C++. That might be the missing piece of the puzzle in this case.