# How to allocation in cudaMalloc...?

Tags: cuda

all.
I am wondering about how to allocation double pointer to cuda.
My code is below.

------------this is structure---

```
typedef struct vertex vertex;

struct vertex {
    unsigned int vertex_id;
    float pagerank;
    float pagerank_next;
    unsigned int n_successors;
    vertex ** successors;
};
```

---

------------these are vertics----

```
vertex * vertices;
vertices = (vertex *)malloc(n_vertices * sizeof(vertex));
vertex *d_vertices;
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_vertices, n_vertices * sizeof(vertex));
```

---

---------these are vertics' succesors. It means double pointers----

```
vertices[i].successors = (vertex**)malloc(vertices[i].n_successors*sizeof(vertex *));
cudaMalloc((void ***)&d_vertices[i].successors, vertices[i].n_successors * sizeof(vertex *)); // error part.
```

---

When I allocate `cudaMalloc((void ***)&d_vertices[i].successors, vertices[i].n_successors * sizeof(vertex *));`

Visual Studio is stopped... I guess pointer error. But I don't know how to double pointer allocation in cuda.
Please, let me know what's wrong in that code.
Thank you so much.

best regards

Comment: Please search. This question has been asked here literally hundreds of time before and there are a lot of answers you can study

Comment: @talonmies I already read several questions. So I understand about why cudaMalloc use double pointer like a (void**). And then I coded like that (void***) type but It didn't work... So I need help...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11874667/681865

Comment: @talonmies Why don't you flag as duplicate?

Comment: @talonmies Thank you so much. Have an awesome day.

Comment: Allocation is a noun.

Comment: @machine_1 that means number of vertices and number of adjacency nodes.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Because my duplicate flag is an instant duplicate close and I want to be certain before I use it